# Find the integral on this curve. (Vector field containing one point that is problematic).

Tags: integration, curves, vector-fields, parametrization

> $\vec \ell(t)=(\sin(t), \sin(t)\cos(t)-1)$
> $t\in[0,2\pi]$. 
> Find $\displaystyle\int_\ell \Big(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}}\Big) \, dx + \Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}}\Big) \, dy$.

My attempt: 
First thing that crossed my mind when I saw this question is I don't want to do the integral with the given parametrization.. so I checked if $\vec F=(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}})$ could be conservative.

I found out that $Q_x=P_y$, in all $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}.$

But I know that now, for any curve I take that rounds $(0,0)$ whatever value of the integral I get, will be the value of any other integral over a curve that rounds $(0,0).$

So I went up and $\vec r(t)=(\cos(t), \sin(t))$.

$$\int_r\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}(\cos^2t+\sin^2t)=\pi.$$

So I thought my normal integral would be the same. 
**Plot twist:** The answer was actually $0$. 

Suspections:

1. I made a mistake calculating the integral. (I checked alot of times so I don't think this is the case).
2. I did all this for nothing because $\vec l$ doesn't round the point $(0,0)$.. ($99\%$).

Questions:

1. How do I check if the given curve rounds the point $(0,0)$?
2. Knowing that my curve doesn't round the point, is there any way to use the fact that the field is conservative there, other than finding the potential function?

Note: Final answer is $0$. 
Any feedback is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: "How do I check if the given curve rounds the point (0,0)?": You have first to make up your mind by (computer) plotting the curve.

Comment: @JeanMarie that's exactly the question.., how do I plot the curve and make sure it doesn't go to $0,0$ (I don't want to use a graphing calculator) , is it just by substituting points?

Comment: Notice that the $y$ co-ordinate is $$y(t) = \frac 12 sin(2t)-1 \le -\frac 12$$

Comment: Yes but my comment was about "making up your mind" = "being convinced that (yes/no) the curve make a complete turn around the origin".

Comment: Fix a set of points close enough, evaluate the value of the curve, and "connect the dots". This will give you an idea of the shape of the parametric curve. In this case, you can also observe that the y coordinate is always negative. Therefore the curve cannot wind around zero. Last, if the field is conservative in $R^2/\{0,0\}$, than locally for every simply connected domain not containing the origin you have a locally defined potential function, therefore the integral over every closed curve contained in such a domain is zero.

Comment: Note that the mere existence of a potential function leads the integral to be zero but you do not have to compute it explicitly

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the explanation, tbh I thought there's some better way to know how the curve looks like, since putting in values just doesn't satisfy me since curves could just move around $(0,0)$ between two points I substituted, but I guess that would be very unlikely to happen, about the existence of the potential function (except at $0,0$), I just realized that $Q_x=P_y$ in a simply connected space leads to conservative field, but here the the space isn't simply connected since theres $0,0$. So I couldn't also say that without finding the potential function?

Comment: Maybe there are better ways I do not know. In this case by the way just knowing that the y coordinate is negative shows that the curve cannot wind zero

Comment: For the conservative field, the semispace S={y<0} is simply connected. So you have a potential function well defined in S whose gradient is your vector field. Since you know that the curve is contained in S, you can forget about the singular point (the origin) outside of S and all results of conservative fields apply. In particular the integral is zero without any further calculation.

Comment: Just saw this. If the vector field is what you have typed in then I do not see it is a conservative vector field.

Comment: Ah sure if the field is  non conservative the story is totally different... well spotted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how the question reads, the line integral of the given vector field over the given curve is zero.

$\vec \ell(t)=(\sin(t), \sin(t)\cos(t)-1), t\in[0,2\pi]$

$\vec F = \displaystyle \Big(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}}, \frac{x}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}}\Big)$

Here is the path from $t: 0 \to 2\pi$.

[image]

The loop to the right of y-axis is clockwise whereas the loop to the left of y-axis is anti-clockwise.

Checking the numerator of the vector field and the symmetry of the curve, it can be shown that the line integral over the part of the curve in the fourth quadrant will cancel out the integral over the part of the curve in first quadrant. Same with the line integral in second and fourth quadrant. However I will show this using Green's theorem.

$Q_x = \dfrac{y^2}{\sqrt2 (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}, P_y = - \dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt2 (x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

$Q_x - P_y = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}}$

For the first loop (for $x \geq 0$) between $0 \leq t \leq \pi$, we are in the clockwise direction.

So the line integral is $\displaystyle \iint_{D_{12}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}} \ dA$

For the second loop, it is $\displaystyle \iint_{D_{34}} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}} \ dA$

The integrand is an even function but with opposite signs in both integrals and regions are symmetric about y-axis. The two integrals will cancel each other out.

---

Some additional details - in cartesian coordinates, the curve is

$(y+1)^2 = x^2 - x^4, \ \ -1 \leq x \leq 1$. So the first integral can be written as,

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_{-1 - x \sqrt{1-x^2}}^{-1 + x \sqrt{1-x^2}} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}} dy \ dx$

And the second integral can be written as,

$\displaystyle \int_{-1}^0 \int_{-1 + x \sqrt{1-x^2}}^{-1 - x \sqrt{1-x^2}} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x^2+2y^2}} dy \ dx$

(Substituting $t = -x$ in the second integral gives you first integral but with opposite sign.)